# Compile-time elimination of if/else branch in C++

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, compiler-optimization, template-specialization

In the following code sample, the `if` statement depends on `bool` template parameter, which is a compile-time constant. Compilers handle this code differently:

- MSVC fails with link error (which is what I expected), because the template function in `else` branch lacks specialisation for `true` template parameter value (even though it is never called).
- GCC and Clang both compile without issues and run-time behaviour is correct. This is obviously because they evaluate the `if` statement at compile time and remove unused branches before linking.

The question is which behaviour is standard-compliant (or is it an undefined behaviour and both are correct in their own way)?

```
#include <iostream>

template<const bool condition>
struct Struct
{
    void print()
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            std::cout << "True\n";
        }
        else
        {
            printIfFalse();
        }
    }

private:
    void printIfFalse();
};

template <>
void Struct<false>::printIfFalse()
{
    std::cout << "False\n";
}

int main()
{
    Struct<true> withTrue{};
    withTrue.print();

    Struct<false> withFalse{};
    withFalse.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, not what you are looking for, but you may look at `if constexpr`

Comment: Both compilers are right. Pedantically, this is unspecified behavior. The C++ standard does not specify what happens here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Even *more* pedantically, it's Undefined Behavior (UB). But in the real world, it's an error or it works. No UB at runtime.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All compilers behave correctly.

Your program is *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*, because you are odr-using `Struct<true>::printIfFalse` through the instantiation of `Struct<true>::print()` required from the call in `withTrue.print();`. A function that is odr-used outside of a *discarded statement* must have a definition in the program, see [[basic.def.odr]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#def.odr-4), otherwise the program is *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*.

A *discarded statement* is what you get if you use `if constexpr` in a template and the statement is not in the chosen branch. So, what you can do to make the program well-formed is to use `if constexpr` instead of `if`. This is a C++17 feature.